# Vue fallback to asset images

Tags: vue.js

I have a bunch of entities I want to display on a page in a Vue 3 application. Each entity should have an image URL. If an entity does not have such a URL, I want to display a default image that's stored in `/src/assets/images/default.png`

So I've created a computed property that returns the image URL, either `entity.url` or the URL above.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, instead of getting the default image I'm getting no image, and the Vue dev webserver returns `index.html`. This is because Vue's handling of static assets doesn't work when the static asset URL is returned in runtime.

The image is shown properly if I hard-code the URL `@/assets/images/default.png`, but not if I return this as a string (dropping the `@` makes no difference).

How can I make Vue handle static assets that are referenced dynamically?

Comment: So I guess you have a `v-for="something in somethings"` and within the loop you call the image. Could you have a wrapping tag around the image with a v-if, like `<template v-if="entity.url"><img :src="entity.url"/></template><template v-else><img...` etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `v-if`/`v-else` to show the appropriate image based on whether `entity.url` exists ..

```
<img v-if="entity.url" :src="entity.url" />
<img v-else src="@/assets/images/default.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3, you can put an `@error` event on the image, so if the URL returns a 404, you can execute arbitrary logic:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const isProfileImageBroken = ref(false);

const handleBrokenImage = () => {
    console.log('image broke');
    isProfileImageBroken.value = true;
};
</script>

<template>
    <i v-if="!auth.user.image || isProfileImageBroken" class="icon-user icon-lg"></i>
    <img
        v-if="auth.user.image && !isProfileImageBroken"
        :src="auth.user.image"
        class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full object-cover"
        @error="handleBrokenImage"
    >
</template>
```

Comment: This is a good start, the problem is that the error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    imageData:{ imgUrl:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png',
    
    }
  },
  methods: {
   getUrlData(data) {
     if (data && data.imgUrl) {
       return data.imgUrl
      }
      else {
       return "@/assets/images/default.png"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <img :src="getUrlData(imageData)">
</div>
```

Try this should work in your case! and let me know if you are getting any errors

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing, and it doesn't work. The static URL does not get resolved.

Comment: actually i tried this way and it worked, that's weird.

Comment: ```return require("@/assets/images/default.png");``` worked for me